# HTML - Display latest image

Tags: html

I had a question about how to make a "gallery" like website.

I have a folder full of thousands of images and I'd like to display them on a page. And I only want to show the 5 first. I found a way to do that with this piece of code :

```
<?php
$folder = 'img/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);
echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'" />';
    echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

But now I'm trying to find a way to add multiple pages. Let's say I have 50 images. I'd like to display the 5 next on pages 2 and so on...
And the url should be something like "http://mygallery.com/page/1".

How would I do that ?

Thanks, have a great day.

Comment: add a pagination feature. by writing code.

Comment: First question, do you know how to fetch a parameter from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Taking into account the url is like www.bobobo.com/gallery?page=1
    // add validation to check
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $pageNo = 1;
    } else {
        $pageNo = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $folder = 'img/';
    $filetype = '*.*';
    $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
    $count = count($files);
    echo '<table>';
    for ($i = ($pageNo * 5) - 5; $i < 5 * $pageNo; $i++) {
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'" />';
        echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

EDIT: So what this is doing now is, it's checking for a parameter in the URL and if it finds a value (isset) it will use that value, else if it's not set, it will set it as 1. Then in the for loop we are doing page number * 5 which if it's 1, will return 5 and take 5, so 0, then we times 5 by page number in the condition which would be 5, so it will get all the images between 0 and 4, so if the page number is 2

(2 * 5) - 5 = 5

(2 * 5) = 10

Page 2 will get all the value sbetween 5 and 9.